# Deploy .R scripts on server for web application

Tags: r, web-applications, server

I want to build a web application that utilizes .R scripts and outputs the results to the user. I know this can be implemented in a number of different ways, but is there a recommended approach to take? i.e. is there a best practice approach to take?

I am unsure whether to host the R code on the web server or use a separate application server for executing the .R scripts.

Comment: Why not `Shiny app`?

Comment: The web app needs to do a lot more than data visualization including writing to remote databases and schedule recurring tasks.

Comment: I would recommend you to look into Rserve also I would recommend you to do those read and writes outside R and only use it for analytics also to package your code vs scripting. Can you give more detailed specs of the service?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your server to serve html pages usable by humans, [Shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com) is a very interesting way to go, as mentioned by @Aleh.

If you rather want a web API (REST) which can be used by computers, have a look at [Plumber](https://www.rplumber.io/)

Comment: Thanks @Pierre Gramme, I like the look of Plumber and will look into it further. The REST API seems to be the more suitable solution (compared to Shiny).